# If I don't want to use a nib file, what is the proper implementation of loadView that sizes the root view correctly?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

There are a bunch of related questions here, but none that feels like a concise or correct answer.  Here's the situation:

I am creating a new ViewController and don't want to use a nib file.  My understanding from the [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is that if I don't want to use a nib, I should implement loadView to manually create my own view hierarchy.

However, its not clear to me how I should properly instantiate self.view with the proper bounds (given this view controller might be used in a bunch of different situations, setting it simply to the screen bounds doesn't feel right).

Somehow the default UIViewController loadView does seem to properly initiate the frame size, but its not clear if I'm writing my own version what I should be doing to do this.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to implement `loadView`. Instead, implement `viewDidLoad` and create and add any and all desired subviews you want. Just add them to the default `self.view`.

If you want to add a view that fills the view controller's view then do something like the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *someView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    someView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [self.view addSubview:someView];
}
```

Comment: That seems to work, and is what I've done in the past, but it seems in contrast with what apple says in the UIViewController doc page, in particular: "If you cannot define your views in a storyboard or a nib file, override the loadView method to manually instantiate a view hierarchy and assign it to the view property."

Comment: You can do that if you want. The only reason you would need to override `loadView` is if you wanted the view controller's root view to be a specific view instead of some empty view.

Comment: I hear you on "need", I'm just trying to figure out the correct way to do this, and it seems like from the docs the correct way is to instantiate a view hierarchy (which I read to mean not just the root view, but all of my subviews) within loadView.  I don't dispute that what you are suggesting works, it just doesn't seem to be what the docs say to do.  Are the docs wrong?  Am I misinterpreting them?

Comment: I have written hundreds of view controllers, all in code. Not one implements ‘loadView‘. All create their view hierarchies in ‘viewDidLoad‘. They all work fine.

Comment: okay, docs are wrong is a fine answer.  Wouldn't be the first time.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

In loadView, you should set the view property of viewController, and nothing else. Adding subviews should be done in viewDidLoad.

```
- (void)loadView {
    self.view = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 80, 40)]; 
}
```

Roopesh Chander has an interesting blog post on which strategy to choose: [loadView vs viewDidLoad
for Programmatic UI Setup](http://roopc.net/posts/2015/loadview-vs-viewdidload/). He recommends setting the frame in loadView rather than viewDidLoad for maximum efficiency.